# Отличие mainClass cls = new childClass() от childClass cls = new childClass();

Tags: c#, .net

**Первый вопрос на стеке, прошу не пинать...**

В *C#* недавно. Не могу понять отличие:

```
mainClass cls = new childClass();
```

от

```
childClass cls = new childClass();
```

`mainClass` абстрактный, `childClass`, как уже догадались, дочерний.
В нем переопределяю метод родительского класса `getInfo()`

Основной код программы:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mainClass _cls = new childClass();
        childClass cls = new childClass();
        cls.getInfo();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Код родительского класса:

```
abstract class mainClass
{
    public virtual void getInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In mainClass Method");
    }
}
```

Код дочернего классa:

```
class childClass : mainClass
{
    public override void getInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In childClass Method;");
    }
}
```

Comment: отличие в типе переменной

Comment: А различия в использовании какие-то имеются?

Comment: Конкретно в этом примере нет. попробуй сделать еще один дочерний класс в котором не использовать override, присвой ее также переменной базового класса и посмотри что выведет getInfo

Comment: Различия есть. Вы не сможете обращаться напрямую к локальным переменным класса если объявите его как материнский. Вы их просто не увидите. Например, для формы `Form1` дочерней формы от класса `Form` если её вызывать как `Form` придётся делать делегаты на методы/переменные чтобы они стали доступными. Поправьте, если не прав.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере отличия лишь в типе переменной, но это (в вашем случае) не влияет на программу.

Все потому, что при вызове функции `getInfo()` языку важен не тип переменной, а реальный тип объекта (могу слегка напутать терминологию, но в c++ реальный тип называется динамическим. Можно ли использовать такое понятие с шарпом - не знаю).
Так вот, перед вызовом `getInfo()` проверяется таблица виртуальных функций и вызывается нужный экземпляр.

А теперь в двух словах о том, когда есть разница.

Представьте, что у вас есть класс `MovableObject` и его подклассы - `Human` и `Car`. В `MovableObject` определён метод `Move` (с модификатором `virtual`), а в подклассах он переопределен (с модификатором `override`).

Тогда что так:

```
MovableObject obj = new Car();
obj.Move();
```

Что так:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.Move();
```

Разницы никакой. Однако код `obj.GetWheels()` не скомпилируется, в отличие от `car.GetWheels()`, т.к. метод `GetWheels` определен лишь для типа `Car`.

И ещё одно: если бы вы не использовали в базовом классе `virtual` и в дочернем `override`, то произошёл бы так называемый **name shadowing**. И тогда код:

```
abstract class A {
     void Print() {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
     }
}

class B : A {
    void Print() {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }
}

// где-то в коде
A obj1 = new B();
B obj2 = new B();
obj1.Print();
obj2.Print();
```

Вывел бы следующее:

```
Base
Derived
```

Т.е. не происходит обращение к таблице виртуальных функций и вызывается функция, принадлежащая типу вашей переменной.